# Parsing and Expanding Markdown

Tags: parsing, templates, markdown

I'm currently trying to develop an templating engine for expanding my custom markdown into full HTML.

I initially thought a recursive approach might work. This would use a tag stack to determine if you were inside another tag, and evaluating the logic of each tag when each are closed. I'm having trouble conceiving of a method that doesn't use indexOf over and over again, and that covers all custom directives I want to support.

---

Syntactically, it uses open and closing tags for each directive. For example:

```
@foreach(item in list)
    <p>text</p>
@endforeach
```

Produces:

```
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
```

(if there were 3 items in the list)

---

```
@foreach(item in list)
    <p>textA</p>
@endforeach
@foreach(item in list)
    <p>textB</p>
@endforeach
```

Produces:

```
<p>textA</p>
<p>textA</p>
<p>textA</p>
<p>textA</p>
<p>textB</p>
<p>textB</p>
```

(if there were 3 items in each list)

---

```
@foreach(item in list)
    @foreach(item in list)
        <p>text_inside</p>
    @endforeach
    <p>text_outside</p>
@endforeach
```

Produces:

```
<p>text_inside</p>
<p>text_inside</p>
<p>text_inside</p>
<p>text_outside</p>
<p>text_inside</p>
<p>text_inside</p>
<p>text_inside</p>
<p>text_outside</p>
<p>text_inside</p>
<p>text_inside</p>
<p>text_inside</p>
<p>text_outside</p>
```

---

Initially, I was thinking about a recursive approach that would use a stack to know whether or not it was inside or outside some other tag. It dawned on me that this is a common function for compilers and as such there should be some popular parsing/compilation algorithm.

I came across the process that a compiler uses (Scanner -> Lexer -> Parser), and I assume that the process of tokenizing input is part of the lexical analysis, but I'm not sure if there is a common algorithm for breaking the code apart for the parser to perform the final logical operation.

At this current point, I'm looking for direction in what method to research, not necessarily someone's implementation (although this might be useful to study).

Comment: Keywords: you can use a _recursive descent parser_ to create an _abstract syntax tree_, that can you then walk down to process the text